# CheckedListBox in VB.NET WPF

Tags: vb.net, wpf, xaml

Hola estoy intentando crear CheckedListBox enlazado a datos en VB.NET, he hecho la implementación pero no se están añadiendo los checkboxs al Listbox.

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="CheckedListBox1" Height="265"  ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Textos}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Esta es la clase que define cada elemento del checkedListbox:

```
Public Class Elementos
    Private _textos As String
    Private _isChecked As Boolean

    Public Sub New(textos As String, ischecked as boolean)
        _textos = textos
        _isChecked = ischecked 
    End Sub
...PROPIEDADES
```

.
.
.
End Class
Clase Main:

```
'declaracion de la lista de elementos
Private _theList As ObservableCollection(Of Elementos)
'property
 Public Property TheList As ObservableCollection(Of Elementos)
        Get
            Return _theList
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Elementos))
            _theList = value
        End Set
    End Property
'creando el objeto en el constructor
 TheList = New ObservableCollection(Of Elementos)
```

Metodo para añadir elementos a la lista:

```
Private Sub InicializarCheckedListBox()
        If Me.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() Then            
            For Each c As ClientesDTO In sectoresList
                TheList.Add(New Elementos(String.Format("Sector: {0}  Cliente: {1}", c.sector, c.nombre)))
            Next
        Else
            Dim d As New InicializarCheckedListBoxCallback(AddressOf InicializarCheckedListBox)
            Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(d)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Alguna idea sobre que me estoy saltando?.
saludos.

Comment: Tenes que ir a la pagina oficial de microsoft, ahi esta todo. Y por otro lado este sitio es para resolver dudas, si pones tu duda de manera mas completa con el codigo que intentaste alguien te ayudara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al parecer cada vez que publico un consulta en SO me salta la chispa, jajajaja
publico lo que me estaba saltando por si alguien desea ahorrarse unas horas de dolores de cabeza.

El tema estaba que no le estaba indicando el contexto en el constructor del Main:

```
TheList = New ObservableCollection(Of Elementos)
        DataContext = Me
```